# ReflectionClass changes name of class and causes fatal error

Tags: php, class, reflection, fatal-error

Getting some serious wierdness when using reflection to get a class instance. The code is so simple I really dont get where this is going wrong, it would seem that reflection is changing the class name. So:

```
$reflect = new ReflectionClass($class);
print_r($reflect);  
ReflectionClass Object
(
  [name] => Db_Table_Data_Binding
)

return $reflect->newInstance(); // fatal error class Db_Table_Binding Not Found
```

even if I wrap it in a if statement to confirm:

```
if($class === "Db_Table_Data_Binding")
{
   return $reflect->newInstance(); // fatal error class Db_Table_Binding 
}
```

Cant really see whats going on here... Any help would be great.

So I worked out what I did wrong for anyone who might stumble across this..

```
class Db_Table_Data_Binding{
   protected $bindTypes = array(
      "integer" => Db_Table_Binding::TYPEINT
   );
}
```

Comment: Does the `Db_Table_Data_Binding` class have a constructor that takes arguments?

Comment: Does `Db_table_Data_Binding` extend `Db_Table_Binding`?

Comment: no and no, even though I left it out of my code for brevity there is a check for constructor above if($reflect->getConstructor()))

Comment: Rut Roe... You just made me realise I had referenced a class Constant wrong and as "Db_Table_Binding, sorry wasting everyones time with my noobery again.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because constructor of your class uses Db_Table_Binding class and it is in different namespace, and your autoloader can't find class definition.

Try at the begining of your script write:

```
use NamespeceWhereUGotThisClass\Db_Table_Binding;
```

Comment: I wasnt/dont use namespacing in PHP. I had referenced a class constant from db_table_binding  and attempted to assign it inside a property array in my db_table_data_binding class. Potato move.